# WPF: Prevent tab from jumping

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I have a wpf tab control and the width are fixed length.
Is there a way for the tabs not to jump around

See g is on top of a tab. Once I click on the g tab, the a tab is on top of g tab. I want the tabs to stay at its location

original:
[image]

once g is clicked 
[image]

Comment: Have you got any event handler behind the code for the tap event of the grid? Provide the code behind the xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how tabs work. The tab at the top would overlap the bottom one and you could not select it anymore. 
Imagine it as a index tabs in a folder